# Aggregate the results of a union query without using raw

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a table that looks like this

```
date                car_crashes         city
01.01               1                   Washington
01.02               4                   Washington
01.03               0                   Washington
01.04               2                   Washington
01.05               0                   Washington
01.06               3                   Washington
01.07               4                   Washington
01.08               1                   Washington
01.01               0                   Detroit
01.02               2                   Detroit
01.03               4                   Detroit
01.04               2                   Detroit
01.05               0                   Detroit
01.06               3                   Detroit
01.07               1                   Detroit
```

I want to know how many car crashes for each day happened in the entire nation, and I can do that with this:

```
Model.values("date") \
.annotate(car_crashes=Sum('car_crashes')) \
.values("date", "car_crashes")
```

Now, let's suppose I have an array like this:

```
weights = [
    {
        "city": "Washington",
        "weight": 1,
    },
    {
        "city": "Detroit",
        "weight": 2,
    }
]
```

This means that Detroit's car crashes should be multiplied by 2 before being aggregated with Washington's.

It can be done like this:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField


when_list = [When(city=w['city'], then=w['weight']) for w in weights]
case_params = {'default': 1, 'output_field': IntegerField()}


Model.objects.values('date') \
    .annotate(
        weighted_car_crashes=Sum(
            F('car_crashes') * Case(*when_list, **case_params)
    ))
```

However, this generates very slow SQL code, especially as more properties and a larger array are introduced.

Another solution which is way faster but still sub-optimal is using pandas:

```
aggregated = false
for weight in weights:

 ag = Model.filter(city=w[‘city’]).values("date") \
 .annotate(car_crashes=Sum('car_crashes') * w[‘weight’]) \
 .values("date", "car_crashes")


 if aggregated is False:
 aggregated = ag
 else:
 aggregated = aggregated.union(ag)


aggregated = pd.DataFrame(aggregated)
if len(weights) > 1:
 aggregated = aggregated.groupby("date", as_index=False).sum(level=[1])
```

This is faster, but still not as fast as what happens if, before calling pandas, I take the `aggregated.query` string and
wrap it with a few lines of SQL.

```
SELECT "date", sum("car_crashes") FROM (


// String from Python
str(aggregated.query)


) as "foo" GROUP BY "date"
```

This works perfectly when pasted into my database SQL. I could do this in Python/Django using `.raw()` but the documentation says to ask before using `.raw()` as mostly anything could be acomplished with the ORM.

Yet, I don't see how. Once I call `.union()` on 2 querysets, I cannot aggregate further.

```
aggregated.union(ag).annotate(cc=Sum('car_crashes'))
```

gives

> Cannot compute Sum('car_crashes'): 'car_crashes' is an aggregate

Is this possible to do with the Django ORM or should I use .raw()?

Comment: In you pandas solution, I'm not clear how the `weight` values are used, is something missing?

Comment: You’re right! Edited.